# How to find the limit distributions of estimators for $\theta$ in $U[0,\theta]$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

I am working on the following exercise:

> Consider the uniform distribution $U[0,\theta]$ and let $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ be an i.i.d. sample from $U[0,\theta]$. We want to estimate $\theta$, so we consider the two unbiased estimators $A,B$ of $\theta$ (i.e. $\mathbb{E}[A] = \theta$ and $\mathbb{E}[B] = \theta$).
>
> $$A_n := \frac{2}{n} \cdot \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$$
> $$B_n := \frac{n+1}{n} \max_i\{X_i\}$$
>
> What is the limit distribution of these estimators (under suitable normalisation)?

I have shown that the estimators are indeed unbiased. But I do not know what to do now. The only theorem I can think of that relates to finding the limit distribution is the CLT. But I do not see how we should apply this here. Could you give me a hint?

Comment: Maybe both will do?

Comment: $n(1-\frac{n}{n+1}\frac{B_n}{\theta})$ has a distribution which tends towards an exponential distribution $\mathrm{Exp}(1)$: see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/549456/2958 for what happens to $\max_i\{X_i\}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first one use the CLT (note that $A_n=2\bar{X})$:

$$\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{\bar{X}-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\to N(0,1)$$

to obtain the following convergence in distribution:

$$\sqrt{3n}\left(\frac{A_n}{\theta}-n\right)\to N(0,1)$$

Henry has answered the second one in the comments before I could write it down. See also [Asymptotic distribution of $X_{(n)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2028147/asymptotic-distribution-of-x-n/2028157) for more details. Esentially, you need to calculate the limiting distribution directly (without CLT).